# scrollview scrolls to middle in android

Tags: android, scrollview

I have a button in one activity and a scrollview in second activity
The scrollview has many views inside it.
when I click on the button in first activity the secind activity is called but the scrollview is automatically scrolled to center of the scrollview.
I want to show the top of the second view the manually scroll down.

Comment: It will easy to help you once you show your xml file and code.

Comment: Did you ever find an appropriate solution? I have the same problem and I think most people in this situation do NOT want to use programmatic scrolling to top because it is messy. I also don't think you need to see the code because this seems to be the default behaviour for buttons in scrollviews, mine's a fab button so don't know if that's any diferent

Answer (score -1):

You can programmatically scroll your scrollview to a certain position. Just use yourScrollView.scrollTo(0,0) at the beginning of second activity. Hope this helps.